# jQuery Mobile get current page

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 and Apache Cordova 2.0.0. I want my app to exit when I press back button but only if current page have ID = feedZive. I am using following code to do it:

```
function onDeviceReady(){
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
    function onBackKeyDown(){
        if ($.mobile.activePage.is("#feedZive")){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        else{
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }

    }
};
```

However it looks like I can't get the current page because I have tried the following code:

```
var activePage = $.mobile.activePage;
alert(activePage);
```

and my alert is showing undefined. I have also tried to change `$.mobile.activePage` to `$.mobile.activePage.attr("id")` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
$(document).live('pagebeforeshow', function() {
    alert($.mobile.activePage.attr('id'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ajD6w/5/

Comment: I do not find activepage documented on the jqm site ... I searched for it [here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/?s=activepage)

Comment: The method can be found here http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/methods.html at the bottom of the document.

Comment: I wrote an example with version 1.3.0 of JQM http://jsfiddle.net/howbizarre/hHxjk/, but strangely, it does not work with JQ 1.9 and next...

Comment: For future reference '.live' has been deprecated for some time now.

Comment: For  jqm 1.4.5 and  jquery 2.01.3  replace '.live' with '.on'.

Comment: You can use `e.target.id` if you're inside `$(document).bind('pageinit', function(e, data){})`

Comment: Quite bizarre indeed, or maybe it's something I don't get about SO,... but if copy the answer straight from S.O. into my editor, I get an error in the JS-console: "SyntaxError: illegal character". However, typing it manually works! ( Taking Phill Healey Jan 22 '15 at 10:26 into account, ofcourse )

Answer (score 18):

Try using

```
var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");
```

I made a working jsfiddle for you
http://jsfiddle.net/Z5Uze/1/

Comment: I am still getting error which I mentioned in second answer. TypeError: $.mobile.activePage is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr("id");

you can see my whole code in fiddle in second answer

Comment: hmm it is strange because if I remove all my script an just paste <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script> then it works, at least at jsfiddle

Comment: is there a way to get a list of ALL pages? I want to compare a url search param against a list of legit pages ... EX: www.myjqmsite.com?page=fatmomma ... then I could `if ( $.mobile.someKindOfPageList[ "fatmomma " ] ){ ... }`

Answer (score 11):

I realise this is an old thread, so this is probably a more recent addition.

Have you tried:

```
var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");
if(activepage[0].id == yourpageid)
{ /*do something here*/ }
```

or another way:

```
var activePage = $.mobile.activePage.attr('id')
if(activepage == yourpageid)
{ /*do something here*/ }
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this, it's working for me:

```
var activePage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
```

Here is a Fiddle with an alert that is working: http://jsfiddle.net/9XThY/3/

Comment: tried using your code and alert(activePage); on second line of code. But I get no alert at all.

Comment: Have you tried to debug the code? If you get no alert it's because the code is breaking in the first line.

Comment: after debug I get the following error:
TypeError: $.mobile.activePage is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

var activePage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;

Comment: Hmm, it's strange, worked for me multiple times, can you post a Fiddle or at least some html markup?

Comment: here is fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4mCRw/ every script is located on my PC so you need to change paths if you want jquery to work. Also the javascript code is located in main.js.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//exit when back button pressed on home screen
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", function() {
        if ($.mobile.activePage.attr('id') == "home") {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        } else {
            navigator.app.backHistory();
        }
    }, false);
}, false);
```

});

Answer (score 2):

We're doing this:

```
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function() {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage");

    var activePageId = activePage[0].id;

    if(activePageId != 'splashPage') { //fix rotation splash flash bug
        $("#splashPage").hide();
    } else {
        $("#splashPage").show();
    }

    switch(activePageId) {
        case 'loginPage':
            loginPageShow();
            break;
        case 'notificationPage':
            notificationPageShow();
            break;
        case 'postPage':
            postPageShow();
            break;
        case 'profilePage':
            profilePageShow();
            break;
        case 'splashPage':
            splashPageShow();
            break;
        case 'timelinePage':
            timelinePageShow();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

And navigation works like this:

```
    $.mobile.loading('hide');
    $(":mobile-pagecontainer").pagecontainer("change", "#timelinePage", {
        transition: 'none'
    });
```

Comment: On it's own this seems a little cumbersome, but assuming you put the logic for each page inside a function then this is actually a nice way to tidy up the overall code. I really need to do some housekeeping on my JQM based app, and this approach would actually work quite well.

Comment: @PhillHealey technically the methods for each page should be inside their own function so that they have their scope, and these method calls are essentially `__page.onShow()` but I didn't really know Javascript at the time of writing so those methods are global, but yes, with proper scope constraints it can work. This is slightly odd to me though, the previous JQM iterations seemed to be a bit less direct (the switch-case is kinda extreme, but it seemed to be the only way to do it). To be fair, with all the magic bugs happening like scroll breaking on iOS, I'd avoid JQM like the plague now.

Comment: True but JQM can be quite a good base when used with other frameworks that fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Jquery mobile 1.4.3 friendly...

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', function () {
    var URL = $.mobile.path.parseUrl(window.location).toString().toLowerCase();

    alert(URL);
});
```

Comment: Would this work when AJAX is used to load content though?

Answer (score -2):

Both of this solutions are good but I needed to put it inside document.ready(function()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var activePage = $.mobile.activePage[0].id;
alert(activePage);
});
```

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong, because the event you need to bind to, is the pageinit event. That is the mobile equivalent of "document ready"! See the documentation. And then you might want to use the pageshow event or any of the other because pageinit alone might fire to early.

Comment: A much cleaner and correct way of doing this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12461117/jquery-mobile-get-current-page/23251934#23251934