# Jquery mobile active page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, mobile

Web-dev newbie reporting in:

I'm writing my first mobile app using jquery mobile and currently stuck there:

For some additional functionality, I would like to get url of current active page. I found out that it can be done using $.mobile.activePage . For example, following code works as expected for me:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(){
    console.log($.mobile.activePage[0].baseURI);
});
```

However, when I press "back" button, `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'activePage' of undefined` appears in console and app hangs.

Question: how do I handle this situation? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12461117/901048

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks but I get absolutely the same situation using code snippets from that answer. As I mentioned before - everything seems to be working fine, problems appear only when using "back" button functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this a little bit different, use this code:

```
$(document).on("pageshow",'.ui-page',function(){
    console.log($.mobile.activePage[0].baseURI);
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/vds2U/82/

Comment: Hi @Juris Upenieks, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: Thanks, works better now, I still get an error while using back button with this function, however whole app doesn`t hang and I get value that I expect.